# How to append "delete button" to EVERY list item that is newly created in JS?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events, dom-manipulation

Shopping List exercise using JS DOM.
My full code: https://codepen.io/lil_a/pen/BaQKvqZ?editors=0110

I have to add a new "Delete" button to every newly created list item. I managed to do that, but it only appends the button I created to the last list item, not other newly added items too. How to do it so there's a new delete button for every list item?

I've searched through similar questions, but generally, the codes were different from mine and I'd have to redo it all. Is there a way to do it with my code?

HTML

```
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul id = "list">
        <li>Notebook<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Jello<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Spinach<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Rice<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Birthday Cake<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Candles<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
    </ul>
```

JS

```
function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li).addEventListener("click", toggleList); 
    //append and toggle on and off new list items
    input.value = "";
    ul>li.appendChild(deleteButton).addEventListener("click", removeItem); 
    //append "delete button" to newly added "li"
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", removeItem);
}
  
function removeItem(){
this.parentNode.remove();
}  

var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "btn");
deleteButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You just need to move the delete button code inside your `createListElement()` function

See I have attached your code see below...

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var list = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li');



function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
  /*Your delete button code MOVED HERE*/
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "btn");
  deleteButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
  /*end*/
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li).addEventListener("click", toggleList); //append and toggle on and off new list items
    input.value = "";
  ul>li.appendChild(deleteButton).addEventListener("click", removeItem); //append "delete button" to newly added "li"
}


function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}



button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);


//Toggle list item on and off when clicked on 
var list = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
list[i].addEventListener("click", toggleList);
}
function toggleList() {
  event.target.classList.toggle("done"); //or this.classList.toggle("done");
}

                      
//Delete list item by clicking on the delete button next to it
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].addEventListener("click", removeItem);
}
  
function removeItem(){
this.parentNode.remove();
}       

//3. BONUS: When adding a new list item, it automatically adds the delete button next to it hint: be sure to check if new items are clickable too!
```

```css
.coolTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  word-spacing: -8px;
  color: tomato;
  text-shadow: 
    -1px -1px 0 firebrick,
    -2px -2px 0 firebrick,
    -3px -3px 0 firebrick,
    -4px -4px 0 firebrick,
    -5px -5px 0 firebrick,
    -6px -6px 0 firebrick,
    -7px -7px 0 firebrick,
    -8px -8px 0 firebrick,
    -30px 20px 40px dimgrey;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.btn {
  display: inline;
  border-color: white;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul id = "list">
        <li>Notebook<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Jello<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Spinach<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Rice<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Birthday Cake<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
        <li>Candles<button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this way of doing the code for next.js? I would like to do the same, but so far reached to the point when the button is attached, but it reacts as on the add item as well as on delete item action... So it's just loop create->delete...

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using based on the above - noticed some of it didn't seem necessary to get the desired results. Like this because seems simpler and straightforward:

````
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var list = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li');

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";

    // Delete Button
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "btn")
    deleteButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Remove "));
    ul>li.appendChild(deleteButton).addEventListener("click", removeItem);

    // Strike-through
    ul.appendChild(li).addEventListener("click", toggleList);
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function removeItem() {
    this.parentNode.remove();
}```

function toggleList () {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
````

Answer (score 0):

See I have used this code and attached it...

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");



function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  // Strike-through
  ul.appendChild(li).addEventListener("click", toggleList); // append and toggle on and off new list items
  input.value = "";

  // Delete button
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "btn");
  deleteButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
  ul>li.appendChild(deleteButton).addEventListener("click", removeItem); // append "Delete button" to newly added "li" and delete list item
}


function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  // event.which works as well
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}


button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);


// Toggle list items on and off when clicked on
var list = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li');

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("click", toggleList);
}

// function to add the 'line-through' (Strike-through) style
function toggleList(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("done"); // or this.classList.toggle("done");
}


// Delete the list item by clicking on the delete button next to it
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("click", removeItem);
}

// function to delete the list item
function removeItem() {
  this.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.btn {
  display: inline;
  border-color: white;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<p id="first">Get it done today</p>
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Notebook <button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
  <li>Jello <button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
  <li>Spinach <button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
  <li>Rice <button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
  <li>Birthday Cake <button class="btn">Delete</button></li><br>
  <li>Candles <button class="btn">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```